# scoket programming for wifi/Bluetooth (python 3.3>)

Tags: python, sockets, bluetooth, wifi

new to programming.. i need little help on how to achieve this  specific task in python .. i need to transfer data between pc to andriod.. i tried socket.. it only works on an active internet connection(i used client /server methodology) .. i want to try it with bluetooth or wifi, if i try pybluez for bluetooth.. andriod deos not support it.. and it kind of only works on linux, for wifi i have no idea how to begin/where to begin, any suggestions are welcome

i run python scripts on andriod using python idle3 from play store(python 3.6>).,on windows i have python 3.6 interpreter

Comment: Wifi is done the same way as wired with the socket module.

Comment: @tgikal can u please elaborate..r provide/suggest any learning material for sockets over wifi/Bluetooth/wired..??

Comment: A wifi connection is still an active connection, so the socket module can use a wifi connection the same way as a wired connection, I use it all the time. I've been looking for Bluetooth myself with little luck.  For wifi I can post some example code tomorrow, not around my computer right now.

Comment: thank u soo much for your time and code I will try and tell u my results..

Answer (score 0):

This is only addressing wifi, this is the general structure for what I usually use.

Server script:

```
import socket, os, time, sys, threading

HOST = '192.168.1.2' # The IP address of this server
PORT = 8888 # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print('Socket created')

#Bind socket to local host and port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print('Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg))
    sys.exit()

print('Socket bind complete')

#Start listening on socket
s.listen(10)
print('Socket now listening')

#Function for handling connections. This will be used to create threads
def clientthread(conn):
    try:
        #Sending message to connected client
        #print('Welcome to the server. Type something and hit enter')
        #conn.send('Welcome to the server. Type something and hit enter\n'.encode()) #send only takes string
        data = ""
        #infinite loop so that function do not terminate and thread do not end.
        toggle = True
        count = 0
        while True:
            data = ""
            #Receiving from client
            data = conn.recv(1024).decode().strip("\r")
            if data:
                print(data)
                conn.send((data + "\r").encode())
            time.sleep(.01)
    except Exception as e:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
        print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)

    #came out of loop
    finally:
        conn.close()

#now keep talking with the client
while True:
    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))

    #start new thread takes 1st argument as a function name to be run, second is the tuple of arguments to the function.
    new_thread = threading.Thread(target = clientthread , args =(conn,))
    new_thread.daemon = True
    new_thread.start()

s.close()
```

Client Script:

```
import socket, time


TCP_IP = "192.168.1.2" # The IP address being connected to
TCP_PORT = 8888 # The socket being connected to

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.connect((self.TCP_IP, self.TCP_PORT))
time.sleep(.5)

while True:
  s.send("Testing".encode()) # Sends a message
  time.sleep(.5)
  data = s.recv(64) # Recieves up to 64 bytes, can be more
  print("recieved:", data)
  time.sleep(.5)

s.close()
```